# How to always start League of Legends in fullscreen mode?

Tags: league-of-legends, ubuntu

I managed to install League of Legends in Ubuntu (and [wrote a review about it](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu))

but, now I want to start the game in fullscreen mode, **always**.

**Question**: *How to always start League of Legends in fullscreen mode*
**Note**: *I just need to now how people do it in Windows. A setting, or a extra command line in the lol launcher like `lollauncher.exe --fullscreen`*?

Comment: did you attempt the code as written? That *USUALLY* shows the first point of research. By default, LoL will only go fullscreen on game launch (When a match is loading), I assume you want the launcher to also be fullscreen?

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 Yes, i tried the code, it did not work. Yes, also the launcher in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can control whether the game itself is full-screen or not with the `game.cfg` file, located in `/League of Legends/Config/game.cfg`. (This file may not exist if the game has never been launched.)

The file is structured as a standard `.ini` file. The section in question is `[General]` and the settings are `WindowMode`, `Width`, and `Height`.

To make the game always full-screen, use something like:

```
[General]
WindowMode=0
Width=1920
Height=1080
```

As for the AIR client, I did some digging around but was unable to locate a configuration file that stored position and such. However, I can confirm that this data is *not* located in the registry.

For posterity, I looked in `/LoL/RADS/projects/lol_air_client*`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the LoL launcher doesn't offer a full screen mode is foreseeable, since it's a desktop application, like word etc.
It's more of a problem that it doesn't even offer window maximization.

To solve this, I would recommend writing a startup script using [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

wine lollauncher.exe & #the ampersand sends applications to the background
sleep 2 #wait for a few seconds for the window to actually spawn.
wmctrl -r PVP.net -b add,fullscreen
fg #only used to get the wine command back to the foreground
```

Please note that you may need to modify the window identifier passed to `-r` as well as the wine command.
This is more of a workaround than a solution, but I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

A clear problem with this is that it depends on the window to actually spawn after the specified amount of seconds. This could be messed up by things like the startup window etc.

A workaround for that (yay, I'm stacking workarounds today) would be to spawn a process in the background that periodically checks if a window named PVP.net is not in fullscreen mode and then adds the needed properties. If you need a script for that, I can whip it up too.

Comment: Windows can spawn? That's new.